# Node.js & Express: How to create many app.get calls with Express.js through "for loop"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

In my server.js, I am trying to loop through the array, that has different urls and use those urls for app.get request function.

Here is my code:

```js
let articleUrlArray = [ 'https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/19/shared-housing-startups-are-taking-off/',
  'https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/19/shared-housing-startups-are-taking-off/',
  'https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/19/my-data-request-lists-guides-to-get-data-about-you/',
  'https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/19/siempos-new-app-will-break-your-smartphone-addiction/',
  'https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/19/la-belle-vie-wants-to-compete-with-amazon-prime-now-in-paris/',
  'https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/19/apple-started-paying-15-billion-european-tax-fine/',
  'https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/19/original-content-dear-white-people/',
  'https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/19/meet-the-judges-for-the-tc-startup-battlefield-europe-at-vivatech/',
  'https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/18/nasas-newest-planet-hunting-satellite-takes-a-stellar-first-test-image/',
  'https://techcrunch.com/video-article/turning-your-toys-into-robots-with-circuit-cubes/',
  'https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/18/does-googles-duplex-violate-two-party-consent-laws/' ];

for(var i = 0; i < articleUrlArray.length-1; i++) {
  app.get('/news/news-desc', function(req, res) {

    var data = '';
    
    var techCrunchNewsItems = [];

    request( articleUrlArray[i], function(err, response, html) {
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);

      if($('.article-content').children('p').eq(0).text().split(' ').length > 50) {

        techCrunchNewsItems.push({
          bodyOne: $('.article-content').children('p').eq(0).text()
        });
      } else {

        techCrunchNewsItems.push({
          bodyOne: $('.article-content').children('p').eq(0).text(),
          bodyTwo: $('.article-content').children('p').eq(1).text()
        });
      }
        
      data = techCrunchNewsItems;

      res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
  })
}
```

As you can see in my code, I have an array call "articleUrlArray" and created "for loop" to loop through this array to get each "articleUrl". Then use that "articleUrl" for request function and get the body content for that url.

No matter whatever happens, I always "only" get the body content for the last url. It is not getting the body content for every urls in the "articleUrlArray".

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the screenshot of what I am getting after running Hugo Nasciutti's solution below:
[image]

Comment: You should do the loop inside of the `app.get('/news/news-desc', function(req, res) { ... })` and because `request` you need to choose a way to deal with that in a loop. Either use something like `async` library or use a Promise variant of `request`.

Comment: So you are trying to get the body of each article (URL)?

Comment: @ionizer Yes, I am trying to get the body of each article(URL). Do you know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const articleUrlArray = [
    'https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/19/shared-housing-startups-are-taking-off/',
    'https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/19/shared-housing-startups-are-taking-off/',
    'https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/19/my-data-request-lists-guides-to-get-data-about-you/',
    'https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/19/siempos-new-app-will-break-your-smartphone-addiction/',
    'https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/19/la-belle-vie-wants-to-compete-with-amazon-prime-now-in-paris/',
    'https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/19/apple-started-paying-15-billion-european-tax-fine/',
    'https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/19/original-content-dear-white-people/',
    'https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/19/meet-the-judges-for-the-tc-startup-battlefield-europe-at-vivatech/',
    'https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/18/nasas-newest-planet-hunting-satellite-takes-a-stellar-first-test-image/',
    'https://techcrunch.com/video-article/turning-your-toys-into-robots-with-circuit-cubes/',
    'https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/18/does-googles-duplex-violate-two-party-consent-laws/'
];

const checkBody = res => (err, response, html) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const articleContent = $('.article-content').children('p')
    const bodyOne = articleContent.eq(0).text()
    const bodyTwo = articleContent.eq(1).text()
    const isExtensive = bodyOne.split(' ').length > 50
    res(isExtensive ? { bodyOne } : { bodyOne, bodyTwo })
}

const getArticle = article => new Promise(res => request(article, checkBody(res)))

app.get('/news/news-desc', (req, res) => {
    Promise.all(articleUrlArray.map(getArticle)).then(data => res.send(JSON.stringify(data)))
})
```

What is really going on here is that I am using a function to bring an array of Promises and when all of them are solved, then, respond the request with the array of objects stringified. I took the liberty of implementing arrow functions and constants.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Your answer definitely loops through the articleUrlArray but it is not outputting what I want. I know you have created "checkBody" function and output either bodyOne or bodyOne & bodyTwo. But I am not getting those. I have attached screenshot of what I am getting. Could you please tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: Try replacing the return with this, `response(isExtensive ? { bodyOne } : { bodyOne, bodyTwo })`, I don't have the full implementation of the function request so I am assuming things. This should bring you the objects.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your solution, but I am getting an error saying, "response is not a function". Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I updated the getArticle and checkBody functions to have their own Promise, take a look at my new answer, I didn't want to do this and stay with the original functionality but I really needed to know the full implementation, tell me if this works.

Comment: I am glad to hear it!

Comment: Hello, I am having another issue. Could you please help me with this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441359/node-js-call-a-method-after-another-method-is-completed